# CUPS + RICOH IM C3500 doesn't accept the paper tray from the print job

Tags: linux, cups, printer

I have a puzzling problem when I print to our RICOH IM C3500 printer from Linux (Debian 11): it ignores the tray settings and stops with an error, because it tries to load from the bypass tray, which is always empty. This problem doesn't happen from Windows.

The strange thing is that the print job on the printer seems to already have the instruction to print from tray 1, but I have to manually select that tray to make it work. How do I troubleshoot this problem further?

This is my printer config on linux:

```
#  lpoptions -l
PageSize/Page Size: Letter Letter.Fullbleed *A4 A4.Fullbleed A5 A5.Fullbleed A6 A6.Fullbleed ISOB5 ISOB5.Fullbleed EnvC5 EnvC5.Fullbleed Env10 Env10.Fullbleed EnvDL EnvDL.Fullbleed 5x13 5x13.Fullbleed EnvC6 EnvC6.Fullbleed Executive Executive.Fullbleed 183x256mm 183x256mm.Fullbleed 128x183mm 128x183mm.Fullbleed Legal Legal.Fullbleed Tabloid Tabloid.Fullbleed EnvMonarch EnvMonarch.Fullbleed 69x95mm 69x95mm.Fullbleed Statement Statement.Fullbleed
Duplex/Double-Sided Printing: None *DuplexNoTumble DuplexTumble
Resolution/Resolution: *600dpi 1200dpi
borderline/Borderline Printing: *off on
edgetoedge/Edge to edge: *no yes
joboffset/Job Offset: off on *shift rotate
WideA4/Wide A4: *no yes
ColorModel/Color Mode: Gray *CMYK
InputSlot/InputSlot: MultiTray *1Tray 2Tray 3Tray 4Tray 5Tray Auto
MediaType/Paper Type: Auto *Plain Recycled Special Special2 Special3 Colored Letterhead Preprinted Labels Coated Bond Cardstock OHP Thick Thick2 Thick3 Thin Middlethick Glossy Envelope
StapleLocation/Staple: *None UpperLeft UpperRight LeftW RightW UpperW CenterW
RIPunch/Punch: *None LeftJP2 LeftUS2 LeftUS3 LeftEU4 LeftNEU4 RightJP2 RightUS2 RightUS3 RightEU4 RightNEU4 UpperJP2 UpperUS2 UpperUS3 UpperEU4 UpperNEU4
N-up/N-up: *1up 2up 4up 6up 9up 16up
NupPageOrder/N-up PageOrder: *RightThenDown DownThenRight LeftThenDown DownThenLeft
```